# TPLink AC600 driver install

Tags: wifi, wlan

I need to install these drivers: http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/Archer-T2U.html#Driver

OS:
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 4):

alex416, 
Saw your post and was also looking for the same answer to your question. Have just fixed my TP-Link AC600 to work on my linux machine.

Follow these instructions (http://hprath.com/2014/06/cisco-linksys-ae6000-ac580-media-tek-mt7610u-mt7630u-mt7650u-linux-x64-driver-patch/) and you should be up and running.

**Note**: The page gives background information to the problem, but you just really need the section titled "**Important – Steps to build driver from sources**". All the commands are done in the terminal:

> Steps:
>
> 1. Unplug Wifi dongle from USB
> 2. update your sources and upgrade if any      sudo apt-get update     sudo apt-get upgrade
> 3. install gnu compiler collection     sudo apt-get install build-essential
> 4. lets install git
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install git
>    ```
> 5. get sources
>
>    ```
>    git clone https://sanrath@bitbucket.org/sanrath/mediatek_mt7610u_sta_driver_linux-64bit.git
>    ```
>
>    - if you have cloned already
>
>      ```
>      cd mediatek_mt7610u_sta_driver_linux-64bit    git pull
>      ```
> 6. build driver
>
>    ```
>    cd mediatek_mt7610u_sta_driver_linux-64bit    
>    make clean
>    make
>    sudo make install
>    ```
>
>    There should not be any errors in last commands
> 7. After the last command connect your USB Wifi adapter to any USB port. Now it must have listed all visible wifi signals(SSIDs). Connect
>      to internet
> 8. open a browser and test internet !!

Not sure what system you have (64-bit or 32-bit) but this is for a 64-bit system.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Strato, I included the more important part from your linked blog post. Please remember to do so in future.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! :D i was getting close to returning it! Thanks so much!!! :D

Comment: @terdon, thanks. I'll remember for next time.